# How to remove part of a URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like this.

`/domains/details.php`  (NOTE: `domains` is dynamic and can be anything)

How do I remove the `domains` part from the URL using .htaccess so the actual lookup is:

`/details.php`

OR it'll be cool if I can get `domains` into the URL.
`/details.php?page=domains`

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: @Lawrence: Thanks!! One quick edit to the above.

What if the URL was http://www.mydomain.com/domains/details.php?user_id=2323

How would the rewrite rule work in that case if I want to capture the URL parameter for user_id (and it is a dynamic variable).

Thanks!!

Comment: I updated my answer to include preserving the existing query parameters.

Comment: @Laurence: Hey thanks so much for the help! Works!!!

Comment: @Laurence.. have another tough one. Tried googling but no luck. Maybe you can help. See comments under your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/details.php$ /details.php?page=$1 [R=301]
```

Leave off the `[R=301]` if you want an internal redirect rather than an actual HTTP redirect.

To preserve existing query parameters you can change the rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/details.php(.*)$ /details.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the following rules to deal with your last request:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!domains/.*)([^/]+)/details.php$ domains/details.php?page=$1 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^domains/details.php$ details.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the reply. The "domains" part is dynamic. Would this htaccess work with that?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Ok, then is there any dependency between "domains" and "domains1" values in your explanation or they may be completely different?